# How to download a file and open it in imageView?

Tags: android, image, picasso

**The URL do not ends in .png or .jpg or any image format**

URL is like this:https://www.abcdef.com/funlearn/downloadFile?id=27
and it is an image.If I paste the URL in any browser it starts downloading the file with .jpg extension as food.jpg.

```
             Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())

            .load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")//working

           // .load("https://www.abcdef.com/funlearn/downloadFile?id=27")//Not working

            .into(image);
```

getting this error :D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Answer (score 0):

Reason is whatever you put inside a" load" should be a file. End thing should be a file. Picasso try to load that file for you. You can use it to load a file in your device sdcard etc. Specifically file should be a image or video. Hope it helps

Comment: Can u explain little bit more @sandesh

Comment: Picasso look for a image or a video file in the link extending the name of the image or video file format..

Comment: And also picasso cannot load a downloading file . Your link is not a link to the file but it is a downloading link. If image is in the server . Picasso loads it.